# QSql connect and read from Database example? - Driver not loaded

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pyqt, qtsql

I've recently started found the need to change from the *_*_mysql module to PyQt's QSql but have nooo idea whatsoever where to start. All I want to do (for now) is read from a database and print the results. This is the furthest I've gotten but I keep getting a "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded" error returned from the query.exec_() function.

Please help!

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")

db.setHostName ( db_host )
db.setUserName ( db_user )
db.setPassword ( db_passwd )
db.setDatabaseName ( db_db )
db.setPort ( db_port )

db.setConnectOptions("CLIENT_SSL=1;CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE=1")
db.open()

defaultDB = QSqlDatabase.database()
query = QSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Users")

qe = query.exec_()
print "query exec" , query.exec_()
if not qe:              # if error
    print QSqlQuery.lastError( query ).text()
else:                   # else display returned values
    while query.next():
        print "query value" , query.value(0).toString()


db.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AAAAHH!!!This always happens! Sit with a problem for a day, finally decide to post and ask about it and about 30 mins after you post your problem, you find a solution!

For those interested, I had the same problem as [this guy](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/3313-QSqlDatabase-QMYSQL-driver-not-loaded).

Basically you HAVE to create a QApplication instance BEFORE your sql code gets executed... i.e

```
# this little monkey has to be here
app = QApplication(sys.argv)


# rest of the code
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")

db.setHostName ( db_host )
db.setUserName ( db_user )
db.setPassword ( db_passwd )
db.setDatabaseName ( db_db )
db.setPort ( db_port )

db.setConnectOptions("CLIENT_SSL=1;CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE=1")
db.open()

defaultDB = QSqlDatabase.database()
query = QSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Users")

qe = query.exec_()
print "query exec" , query.exec_()
if not qe:              # if error
    print QSqlQuery.lastError( query ).text()
else:                   # else display returned values
    while query.next():
        print "query value" , query.value(0).toString()


db.close()
```